# GDAL PAM file specification

Tags: gdal

I'm looking to write my own aux.xml files to store additional metadata related to a GeoTIFF, e.g. the orientation of the drone, camera gain, wavelength associated with each band, etc.

Is there a specification available for the PAM files?

Comment: There is this source code https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gcore/gdalpamdataset.cpp
and some PAM related tests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/pam.py and API reference https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALPamDataset.html. I could not find XSD schema or wiki documents.